# Django - Template does not show DetailView

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

I am encountering the following error when trying to set DetailView for each of the post in my postlist:

> NoReverseMatch at /blog/post-list/ Reverse for 'postdetail' with
>   keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['blog\/post-list/(?P\d+)/$']

Here the code:

**views.py**

```
def PostList(request):
    postlist = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        "postlist":postlist
    }
    template_name = "postlist.html"
    return render(request,template_name,context)   

def PostDetail(request,id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=id)
    context = {
        'post':post
    }
    template_name = "postdetail.html"
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

**postlist.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {% for item in postlist %}
            <ul>
                <li><h3>Title:</h3> {{ item.title }} <smal>{{ item.timestamp }}</smal></li>
                <li><h3>description:</h3>{{ item.description }}</li>
                <li><h3>Updated:</h3>{{ item.updated }}</li>
                <li><h>Author: {{ item.Author }}</h></li>
                {{ item.id }}
            </ul>
            <a href="{% url 'blog:postdetail' id=post.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ item }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^post-list/$',views.PostList,name ='postlist'),
    re_path(r'^post-list/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.PostDetail,name="postdetail"),
    path ('post-create',views.CreatPost, name='post-create'),
    re_path (r'^post-list/update/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.PostUpdateis,name='update-post'),
    # re_path(r'^(?P<slug_post>[-\w])+/$',views.PostDetail,name="postdetail"),    
]
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: You write `{% url 'blog:postdetail' id=post.id %}`, but your variable that holds the post is `item`, not `post`, so it should be `{% url 'blog:postdetail' id=item.id %}`.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem Yes tnx a lot very helpful. i realized what is problem .